# imported class doesnt show in UI in Layout

Tags: android, layout

I have created  class "Tlx_bar.java" in a project "NASA_TLX_Bar", and i would like to get this class into other projects with import or rather include it into their buildpath. By now i can call

```
import com.example.nasa_tlx_bar.*;
```

and also have the nasa_tlx_bar library in the "Referenced Libraries" folder.

My problem now is, because the nasa_tlx_bar extends View i assumed, that it would show up in the Userinterface when i create the layout xml, but it doesnt show up in the "Custom & Library Views" field.

Am i missing a vital step with the import? or something else?

Thanks for looking over this issue :)

Comment: did you try to add the view element by yourself in the xml-code not in the wysiwyg-editor?

Comment: they never show in "Custom & Library Views". You just type in the XML the complete package/class name and it will be fine.